# Android parse RSS feed from ASPX URL

Tags: android, asp.net, rss, httpclient

I'm trying to parse a RSS feed from an url that ends with .aspx. I can't modify the .aspx file unfortunatly.
The problem is that the first line of the file crashes my whole app.

```
    <rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
        <channel>
        ...
        </channel>
    </rss>
```

When I tried my own RSS feed without the rss tag it worked perfectly.
I'm parsing the information with this little code below:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.url.com/rssfeed.aspx");

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Is there a way that I can make Java ignore the first and the last line of the .aspx file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

https://github.com/matshofman/Android-RSS-Reader-Library

or something similar. Do some research on a RSS reader library. its a pretty common thing to do.